# About continuous linear functional on the topology generated by linear functionals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

I am self-studying P. Lax's functional analysis book.
Here is an exercise in p123. it is supposed to be very easy, but I really couldn't see it.

Could you anyone help me out? Thanks.

Let $\{ l_\alpha\}$ be a collection of linear functions in a linear space  $X$ over $\mathbb{R}$ that separates points; that is, for any two distinct points $x$ and $y$ of $X$ there is an $l_\alpha$ such that $l_\alpha(x) \neq l_\alpha(y)$.

Assertion: A linear functional $l$ is continuous in the topology generated by $\{ l_\alpha\}$ iff it is a *finite* combination of the $l_\alpha$.

Comment: See theorem 3.9 and 3.10 in Rudin's Functional Analysis

Comment: If $l$ is continuous $U = l^{-1}(-1,1)$ is open. Thus there are $l_1,\dots,l_n \in \{l_\alpha\}$ and $\varepsilon \gt 0$ such that $U \supset \bigcap_{i=1}^n \{x\,:\,|l_i(x)| \lt \varepsilon\}$. Deduce that $\ker{l} \supset \bigcap_{i=1}^n \ker{l_i}$ and linear algebra tells you that this means that $l$ is a linear combination of the $l_i$.

Comment: @t.b. : What does $|l_i(x)|\le \epsilon$ mean ?is it not true that $l(x)$ is a discrete point ? Can you help me to get rid of confusion . Thank you .